# What is wrong with this $1/k^{\alpha}$ series proof?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Let our series be
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^{\alpha}}
$$
and try to prove that it converges when $\alpha>1$ and diverges when $\alpha<1$.

A series converges if a sequence of its partial sums converge. Now
$$
S_n=1+\frac{1}{2^{\alpha}}+\frac{1}{3^{\alpha}}+\dots+\frac{1}{n^{\alpha}}
$$
and
$$
S_{n+1}=1+\frac{1}{2^{\alpha}}+\frac{1}{3^{\alpha}}+\dots+\frac{1}{n^{\alpha}}+\frac{1}{(n+1)^{\alpha}}.
$$
Let's prove that this sequence is Caychy sequence when $\alpha >1$:
$$
|S_{n+1}-S_{n}| = \frac{1}{(n+1)^{\alpha}}\le\frac{1}{n+1}<\frac{1}{n}<\varepsilon,
$$
when $n$ is big enough. Alright, sounds good, but I noticed that I could place $\alpha=1$ there and still make it smaller than $\varepsilon$:
$$
|S_{n+1}-S_{n}| = \frac{1}{(n+1)^{\alpha}}=\frac{1}{n+1}<\frac{1}{n}<\varepsilon,
$$
Which to my knowledge is not true. What I'm understanding wrong here?

Comment: Your definition of Cauchy is not quite right. For any $\epsilon$ you must produce $N$ such that $|S_n - S_m| < \epsilon$ for any $n,m \ge N$.

Comment: Oh yeah! Have to start over...  This made the problem more difficult than I thought at first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recall that the condition

$$S_{n+1}-S_{n} \to 0$$

is necessary but not sufficient for convergence.

Cauchy requires that eventually $|S_{m}-S_{n}|<\epsilon$. To prove that the series converges we can also use integral test or Cauchy condensation test.